# How to copy csv file without automatic conversion to Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to copy a csv file to a new location. I am using the following code:

```
import os
import shutil

if os.path.exists("newfile.csv"):
  shutil.copy("newfile.csv", "C:\\User\\Pro\\")
```

But this is automatically converting the csv into excel. So `newfile.csv` becomes `newfile.xlsx`. How can I avoid this automatic conversion and copy the csv file as a csv file?

Comment: If you are on a windows machine and you click on a file with the extension `.csv` windows will likely choose excel as the application it should open the file with. It has nothing to do with the contents of the file. I suspect the file has not changed at all as you copied it.

Comment: What's the path in destination_folder? Are you sure its converting to an .xlsx file or are you opening it in excel?

Comment: What is the name of the file after it is copied?

Comment: @0x263A File name is the same!

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum it is a windows locations `"C:\\User\\Pro\\"`

Comment: As @AndrewAllaire said, Excel is probably the default application for .csv files. You may have overridden the default for the original file, but that override isn't copied.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire Yeah the default app is excel for open. But I am trying to access the file through `pandas.read_csv()`. When the file gets copied, it is getting copied as excel. That is the problem.

Comment: @VancePyton So the end result of this operation is the file at this location: ```C:\Users\Pro\newfile.xlsx```?

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum yeah, it is getting copied as `xlsx` file.

Comment: That is fascinating, I don't know why `shutil.copy()` would do that. Is it possible that the `xlsx` file was not really created by `shutil.copy()`, perhaps because `newfile.csv` did not actually exist in the directory your python had as the cwd, and that the `xlsx` file was already there for some other reason?

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this bug. I think what @AndrewAllaire is saying might be the case. Perhaps the newfile.xlsx already existed. If you delete the .xlsx file and run the script again, what happens?

Comment: Also could you maybe add a `print("File was found")` inside the `if` block before re-running it.

Comment: I tested it with the filename newfile.xlsx already existing in the moved location, it didn't change anything. Could you share your code that is reading in the csv? I don't think the bug is inside the script you have listed; its either an external app, file, or how you're reading in the csv.

Comment: It's hard to believe even Windows will change the content of a file when doing a simple copy operation. Maybe checksum the source and destination files to confirm they are identical... https://ladedu.com/how-to-verify-a-md5-or-sha-checksum-on-windows-10/

Comment: @AndrewAllaire yes, I did. the same thing happens.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum at this point, I am only doing this. It is in a `main.py` file and I am not adding any extra functions. Just those two lines of code.

Comment: so if you add this line ```print(os.path.exists(r"C:\\User\\Pro\\newfile.csv"))``` at the end of the script, what happens?

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum this is interesting. It prints True. But `pandas.read_csv` is generating an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'newfile.csv'`

Comment: It is working after I used `r` with path string like this `r"C:\\User\\Pro\\newfile.csv"`

Comment: Protip, if you are going to do much python and deal with paths, especially on windows, then `from pathlib import Path` is your friend. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html